# sftp from mainframes to other server

Tags: unix, sftp

I need a unix script that would take the file from a mainframe to another server.

Presently i am using a ndm but i am not knowing what the changes would be required to change to sftp.

Can you please provide some code that would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

some code that we use ...

```
sftp admin@xxx.xxx.224.22 <<EOF
cd /var/www/vhosts/yyyyy.com/subdomain/sandbox/
get sandbox.sql
get sandbox.tgz
exit
EOF
```

modify it and call it from the server you want to have the files in...